# ErrorException [ Notice ]: Undefined offset: 1

Tags: php

I need help in my code, exactly i know where is the problem, but i dont know how to fix it.

I'm catching a stats from oter service, and when this stats are on "-" and i will turn on my cron then i got an problem from :

ErrorException [ Notice ]: Undefined offset: 1

The codeline is:

```
       <?php

            class Model_Datasource_1 extends Model_Datasource implements Model_Datasource_Service {
protected $usernameList = array();

protected $userEarnings = array();

public function getUserEarnings($date, $serviceUsername) {
if (empty($this->userEarnings[$date][$serviceUsername])) {
    $this->curl->getContent('hidden link', Curl::POST, array(
    'performer' => $serviceUsername,
    'stat' => 'Statystyka'
    ));

    $content = $this->curl->getContent('hidden link' . date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date)) . '&params[endDate]=' . date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date)));

    preg_match('#<span class="payout">([0-9\.]+) USD</span>#si', $content, $matches);

    $this->userEarnings[$date][$serviceUsername][] = array(
    'statDatetime' => date('Y-m-d ', strtotime($date)) . date('H:i:s'),
    'statEarnings' => (float) $matches[1]
    );
}

return (!empty($this->userEarnings[$date][$serviceUsername])) ? $this->userEarnings[$date][$serviceUsername] : array();
}

public function getUsernameList() {
if (empty($this->usernameList)) {
    $pageNumber = 1;
    do {
    $content = $this->curl->getContent('hidden link' . $pageNumber . '|1|1&filter=A');
    preg_match_all('#<form id="performer_([^"]+)" action="hidden link', $content, $matches);
    $this->usernameList = array_merge($this->usernameList, $matches[1]);

    $pageNumber++;
    } while (count($matches[1]) == 5);
}

return $this->usernameList;
}

public function logIn($userName, $userPassword) {
$this->curl->getContent('hidden link');

$content = $this->curl->getContent('hidden link');
preg_match('#<input type="hidden" name="ref" value="([^"]*)">#Usi', $content, $matches);

$content = $this->curl->getContent('hidden link', Curl::POST, array(
    'studio' => $userName,
    'password' => $userPassword,
    'ref' => $matches[1],
    'Submit' => 'Zalogowanie tutaj'
    ));
}

public function logOut() {
$this->curl = new Curl();
}

}

   ?>
```

Comment: Which line is provoking the error?

Comment: I have addead a full code up, the line whos generating the error is: 

'statEarnings' => (float) $matches[1]

Comment: Now i'm gettin an error : ErrorException [ Notice ]: Undefined offset: 1

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean:

```
'statEarnings' => floatval($matches[1])
```

Comment: I was wondering what `(float)` was doing there, I think you can only invoke (int)?

Comment: The problem is when i get stats on minus, when all stats are on plus that code work very good :)

Comment: Well that's not the same error you posted in your original question, is it.

Comment: Yeah, but when i posted original question i had problem with that problem in topic :)

Comment: Kinda? Maybe? - `Now i'm gettin an error : ErrorException [ Notice ]: Undefined offset: 1`

Comment: Dunno, obviously the preg_match isn't returning an array from minus values, but I know nothing about regex.